# i want to send a information to customer mail but not using mail id how it possible?

Tags: apex, email

send a mail to customer but without using mail id ?
how it is possible?

```
public class Demo{


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use User id as Target object id to send an email without using
>   emailId.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setTargetObjectId(UserId_To_Whom_You_Want_To_Send_Email);
email.setHtmlBody('Test Body');
email.setSubject('Test Subject');
email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{email});
```

please refer [SingleEmailMessage Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm)